# Unable to upload videos using web API portal, unauthorized 401 error Azure Video Indexer

Tags: azure, http-status-code-401, unauthorized, azure-video-indexer

I was trying to upload a video using the "Try It" feature under [Upload Video API](https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Upload-Video/console) .  I created a trial account and the product key and account number from the developer portal is verified to be correct. I am getting the following message:

Response status
401 Unauthorized

Response latency
60 ms
Response content
x-ms-request-id: 4xxxx5-xxxx5-4xxxxx-8a33-xxxxxxxxx
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 18 Nov 2020 21:56:24 GMT
Content-Length: 119
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
"ErrorType": "USER_NOT_ALLOWED",
"Message": "User not allowed to modify account '06xxxxf-0xfx-4xx0-bxxb-e67f13cxxx5c'."
}

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have not provided the access token.

[image]

As per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/video-indexer-use-apis#obtain-access-token-using-the-authorization-api) , you will have to obtain the access token.

So if you are doing it in the portal, you could use this [Get Account Access Token endpoint](https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Get-Account-Access-Token/console)

[image]

Set the AllowEdit to true, as you are performing a upload action.

**Output :**

[image]

Now in the [Upload Video](https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Upload-Video/console) endpoint , you can paste the access token obtained from the previous step in the **access token parameter**.

[image]

Comment: @DS-0832 - Did the above solution help ?